# Use TOP (1) specification when searching for primary key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When querying a table using its primary key, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE myPrimaryKey = @bar;
```

would it make sense/be faster to use a `TOP (1)` specification?

```
SELECT TOP (1) * FROM foo WHERE myPrimaryKey = @bar;
```

Or is SQL Server smart enough to stop searching after it's found the primary key?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the execution plans of those two queries?

Comment: Or just start the profiler from SSMS and look there.

Comment: Well yes, I could, but as this is not exactly my cup of tea, I wouldn't even know what to look for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, In your particular case using the `TOP (1)` is not useful at all.

The `TOP` clause is applied after the entire query is processed, so it's useful only to limit the overhead of a possibile high data flow between the server and the client, or when you want to limit no matter what the amount of rows you will retrieve from the server.

The reason because I say that `TOP` is applied after everything else is because it needs to have the ordered data, so it has to work after the last evaluated clause: `ORDER BY`.
Also `TOP` can let you retrieve the first `x percent` rows using `TOP(x) PERCENT`, so again, it needs to know the amount of rows and their order.

A simple example is the biggest enemy of a development DBMS: `SELECT * FROM Table` (I've specified development because that's the only environment where that kind of query should be seen).

Sometimes I use a `SELECT * FROM` kind of query when I have to understand what kind of data (not data type) I have to expect when I'll develop something that has to use that table.
Since I want to write a very short query and all I need is a bunch of records, I use the TOP clause: `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Table`

SQL Server still process the query as `SELECT * FROM Table` but it will only send me back the first 5 rows.

You can try out yourself: write a query that should retrieve more than 1 row, check its execution plan, add the `TOP` clause and check the execution plan again. They will be the same in both cases.

The image down there shows how `TOP` impacts on your query. The query without `TOP` returned around 40700 rows. You can clearly see that the Wait time on server is only 2ms but all the rest of the time (267ms) is spent in downloading data.

[image: TOP Performances]

Comment: So using `TOP` will never make the query itself process any faster? I've always been under the impression that it did. Learned something new then.

Comment: @StanBruce just to illustrate, this is what an execution plan can look like for a simple statement `SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE ID = <val>` and the same with `TOP`: `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM <table> WHERE ID = <val>`: http://i.imgur.com/dzPId2a.png  when you mouseover the `Clusered Index Seek` is exactly the same in estimated costs only the `TOP` came after it, too.

Comment: TOP does not make the query faster itself, it may reduce the data transferred from the server to the client, so it may speedup queries that exceed that number of rows. You can try out the example I did in my answer. Take a big table in your development database and select every row. The query itself is fast, is very simple for the database. The hard past is transfer the whole bunch of data from the db to you. I may add screenshots if you want me to be more clear ;)

Comment: @StanBruce I added an image of a real test

Comment: @mordack550 the image you posted does not address what OP asked for (selecting a row with a specific **primary key**, with and without `TOP` so only returning one row in both cases)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I know, I wanted to address the opposite. The case when TOP really makes a difference. I may add another image directly addressing the op question.

Comment: a tip how to accelarate top  [claus]:(http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2053/trick-to-optimize-top-clause-in-sql-server/)